# Applying a scope from a related model to a query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, scope

I have two models, `User` and `Payment`. A `User` `has_many` `Payment`s and a `Payment` `belongs_to` a `User`.

I'm querying all Payments for the current month like so:

```
@payments = Payment.approved.current_month
```

But I need to exclude Payments made by superadmin Users, for which I have the scope `:exclude_superadmins` in my `User` model which will exclude from a `User` query all users that are superadmins (determined by the `User.permission_level`).

I can't find a way to chain the `:exclude_superadmins` `User` scope to the `Payment` query, as it results in

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `exclude_superadmins' for #<Payment
```

I've tried including, joining and merging the table Users in the query with no success either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [merge](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge). Below is an example on how it would be used in your scenario.

```
@payments = Payment.joins(:users).approved.merge(User.exclude_superadmins)
```